# How to format a fixed-length number as a binary string?

Tags: postgresql, number-formatting

I'm trying to wrap my head around how Postgres represents numbers as binary.  How would I format a fixed-length number as a string of ones and zeroes?
Example:

```sql
select fmt((1<<0)::int2); -- something like 0000 0000 0000 0001
select fmt((1<<2)::int2); -- something like 0000 0000 0000 0100
```

EDIT: I'm working on postgres 14.

Comment: How do you get '10000000000000000' out of `1<<0`, I wonder.

Comment: Your text representation seems flipped around? And why 17 digits instead of 16? What is the exact data type you want to return? Please always disclose your version of Postgres.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter edits applied to address your postgres-version and typo comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast `integer` or `bigint` to `bit(n)`. The rest is easy.

Notably, there is **no cast for `smallint` (`int2`)** in standard Postgres - up to & including version 15:

```
test=> SELECT castsource::regtype
test-> FROM   pg_cast
test-> WHERE  casttarget = 'bit'::regtype;
 castsource  
-------------
 bigint
 integer
 bit
 bit varying
(4 rows)
```

So drop the cast to `smallint` (`int2`). `1<<2` returns `integer` (`int4`), cast that to `bit(16)`.

##### `varbit` output

```
SELECT (1 << 0)::bit(16);  -- 0000000000000001
SELECT (1 << 2)::bit(16);  -- 0000000000000100
```

##### `text` output

With a blank after every 4 digits:

```
SELECT rtrim(regexp_replace((1 << 0)::bit(16)::text, '(\d\d\d\d)', '\1 ', 'g'));  -- 0000 0000 0000 0001
SELECT rtrim(regexp_replace((1 << 2)::bit(16)::text, '(\d\d\d\d)', '\1 ', 'g'));  -- 0000 0000 0000 0100
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8tW7_JEV)

#### Original answer to first draft of question

Assuming from your display:

- Reversed notation with most significant bit to the right.
- `'00100000000000000'` for `1<<2` - `'01000000000000000'` being a typo.
- 17 digits (though just 16 would seem more appropriate to match the scope of `smallint`).

##### `varbit` output

To return want `bit varying`, shift by `17-n` (*17* being the desired length of the bit string, then cast to `bit(32)`, matching the whole `integer`, and take a substring from position *15* (= *32-17*). This is a bit shorter & cheaper than casting to `text` and back:

```
SELECT substring((1 << (17-0))::bit(32), 15);  -- '10000000000000000'
SELECT substring((1 << (17-2))::bit(32), 15);  -- '00100000000000000'
```

[`substring()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-bitstring.html#FUNCTIONS-BIT-STRING-TABLE) is defined for `varbit`, too.

##### `text` output

```
SELECT reverse((1 << 0)::bit(17)::text);  -- '10000000000000000'
SELECT reverse((1 << 2)::bit(17)::text);  -- '00100000000000000'
```

[`reverse()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) is defined for `text`, but not for `bit`. But since we return `text` anyway ...

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rEd0oCQa)